# Значки для приложения

Tags: android, activity

Допустим, если мне не нужно программно менять цвета моих значков, то можно ли добавить для своего проекта один большой значок (256х256) в папку Drawable и не использовать другие (разного разрешения), как рекомендует документация? На тестовом проекте все выглядит очень даже неплохо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** Спасибо за ответ! Вот нагуглил по теме векторного формата для андроид на хабре:

Часть 1 (habrahabr.ru/post/265601/)

Часть 2 (habrahabr.ru/post/265603/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации рекомендуется разделять по разрешениям не из странной прихоти разработчиков платформы, чтобы замучить программистов нудятиной, а по вполне прозаическим причинам.

Дело в том, что для устройств с небольшим количеством памяти, иконки размером 256х256 положат это устройство по OME довольно быстро.

Устройства с небольшой производительностью будут впадать во фризы или вовсе ложится по ANR при попытках обработать большое количество изображений в таком разрешении.

Для решения этих проблем и используется разделение графики по необходимому минимуму в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

Если вы хотите использовать одну иконку под все разрешения - используйте векторный формат, Google недавно выпустил официальную библиотеку поддержки этого формата.